# how to use dom php parser

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I'm new to DOM parsing in PHP:
I have a HTML file that I'm trying to parse. It has a bunch of DIVs like this:

```
<div id="interestingbox"> 
   <div id="interestingdetails" class="txtnormal">
        <div>Content1</div>
        <div>Content2</div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="interestingbox"> 
......
```

I'm trying to get the contents of the many div boxes using php.
How can I use the DOM parser to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First i have to tell you that you can't use the same id on two different divs; there are classes for that point. Every element should have an unique id.

Code to get the contents of the div with id="interestingbox"

```
$html = '
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="interestingbox"> 
   <div id="interestingdetails" class="txtnormal">
        <div>Content1</div>
        <div>Content2</div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="interestingbox2"><a href="#">a link</a></div>
</body>
</html>';


$dom_document = new DOMDocument();

$dom_document->loadHTML($html);

//use DOMXpath to navigate the html with the DOM
$dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom_document);

// if you want to get the div with id=interestingbox
$elements = $dom_xpath->query("*/div[@id='interestingbox']");

if (!is_null($elements)) {

  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo "\n[". $element->nodeName. "]";

    $nodes = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
    }

  }
}

//OUTPUT
[div]  {
        Content1
        Content2
}
```

Example with classes:

```
$html = '
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="interestingbox"> 
   <div id="interestingdetails" class="txtnormal">
        <div>Content1</div>
        <div>Content2</div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="interestingbox"><a href="#">a link</a></div>
</body>
</html>';

//the same as before.. just change the xpath

[...]

$elements = $dom_xpath->query("*/div[@class='interestingbox']");

[...]

//OUTPUT
[div]  {
        Content1
        Content2
}

[div]  {
a link
}
```

Refer to the [DOMXPath](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) page for more details.

Answer (score 6):

I got this to work using [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) as a start:

```
$html = file_get_html('example.com');
foreach ($html->find('div[id=interestingbox]') as $result)
{
    echo $result->innertext;
}
```

Comment: this is very easy to use

Answer (score 0):

Very nice function from http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?611393-php5-need-something-like-innerHTML-instead-of-nodeValue

```
function innerXML($node) 

{ 

    $doc  = $node->ownerDocument; 

    $frag = $doc->createDocumentFragment(); 

    foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) 

    { 

        $frag->appendChild($child->cloneNode(TRUE)); 

    } 

    return $doc->saveXML($frag); 

}  


$dom = new DOMDocument(); 

$dom->loadXML(' 

<html> 

<body> 

<table> 

<tr> 

    <td id="foo">  

        The first bit of Data I want 

        <br />The second bit of Data I want 

        <br />The third bit of Data I want 

    </td> 

</tr> 

</table> 

<body> 

<html> 



'); 

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 

$node = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//td[@id='foo' ]"); 

$dataString = innerXML($node->item(0)); 
$dataArr = explode("<br />", $dataString); 

$dataUno = $dataArr[0]; 
$dataDos = $dataArr[1]; 
$dataTres = $dataArr[2]; 

echo "firstdata = $nameUno<br />seconddata = $nameDos<br />thirddata = $nameTres<br />"
```

Answer (score 0):

WebExtractor: https://github.com/knyga/webextractor
It can parse page with css, regex, xpath selectors.

Look package and tests for examples:

> use WebExtractor\DataExtractor\DataExtractorFactory; use
>   WebExtractor\DataExtractor\DataExtractorTypes; use
>   WebExtractor\Client\Client;
>
> $factory = DataExtractorFactory::getFactory(); $extractor =
>   $factory->createDataExtractor(DataExtractorTypes::CSS); $client = new
>   Client; $content =
>   $client->get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_Winter_Olympics');
>   $extractor->setContent($content); $h1 =
>   $extractor->setSelector('h1')->extract();