# text-overflow:ellipsis on a link

Tags: css

I want to use text-overflow property on a link. I work for a paragraph but not for a link.

Here is the HTML code

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
        <p>the text is too long</p>
    </li>   
    <li>
         <a href="javascript:alert('test')">the link is too long</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the css code :

```
a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

}
p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

See example on http://jsfiddle.net/corinnekm/LLVDB/

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

an `<a>` tag is an inline element, you can only apply ellipsis to a block element, try `a { display: block; }` and it works

Answer (score 9):

http://primercss.io/utilities/ has a css truncate set of rules.
See https://jsfiddle.net/illegs/g04L9xd6/

```
.css-truncate.css-truncate-target,
.css-truncate .css-truncate-target {
display: inline-block;
max-width: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: top
}

.css-truncate.expandable.css-truncate-target,
.css-truncate.expandable.css-truncate-target,
.css-truncate.expandable:hover .css-truncate-target,
.css-truncate.expandable:hover.css-truncate-target {
max-width: 10000px !important
}

<span class="css-truncate expandable">
<span class="branch-ref css-truncate-target"><a href="javascript:alert('test')">the link is too long</a></span>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Gilles, helped me a lot.

Comment: This is a good answer, but unfortunately for anyone who tries to use it with a button instead of a link, be aware that a Chrome bug will cause the text to just be chopped off instead of showing the ellipsis.  This can be demonstrated by running the JSFiddle in the answer and just changing the a tag to a button tag. 
 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107014