# Truncating multiline texts with links (<a> tags) in truncated part with css

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, multiline, truncate

I have a div which gets populated dynamically with some text that may or may not contain a link(s).

For eg:

```
<div>Welcome to Stackoverflow.
     Someone will provide an answer to this question.
     Just sit back and relax, or go check your
     <a href="http://gmail.com">mail</a>
</div>
```

When I truncate it using solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines), the output I get is:

```
Welcome to Stackoverflow. Someone will
provide an answer to this... mail
```

The reason this is happening is that the anchor (a) tag is an inline element while the "ellipsis" property works only on block elements. Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820007/text-overflowellipsis-on-a-link).

I can assign the last-child A tag display:block, but if it's not part of the truncated text, then the text following it breaks to a new line.

Interestingly, if I simply add a "." (period) or even a non-breaking space at the end after the link, then the truncation occurs normally and the  link does not jump in after the ellipsis.

Is there a cleaner approach?

Just to add: I'm looking for a solution that need not be cross-browser, but works for Chrome, since I'm coding for CEF.

Answer (score 0):

Assign "display:inline-block" to the last-child A, instead of "display:block" ;-)

UPDATE:

I read js solution proposed in thread you linked and I updated that jsFiddle into [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/VpmbL/2126/). Is your desired behaviour?

HTML:

```
<div style="width:200px; height:80px; border:1px solid red">Welcome to Stackoverflow.
     Someone will provide an answer to this question.
     Just sit back and relax, or go check your
     <a href="http://gmail.com">mail</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").ellipsis();
});
```

Comment: That would also create a line break for whatever follows the A tag (in case its not the last element). Plus this technique also fails for the case where there are 2 A tags in the truncated part.

Comment: I think you've missed writing the ellipsis function in the fiddle. However, I was looking for a CSS only solution (as mentioned in the title). Thanks for taking the time though.