# Parse HTML and show result

Tags: php, html, parsing

is there a function in PHP that could parse the html data below to show the following.

```
John Lastname
my address
24
1998-03-20 8:15:31 pm
anything
1.1.1.1
```

This is the html

```
<b>Name:</b> John Lastname<br />
<b>Address:</b> [my address] <br />
<b>Age:</b> [24] <br/><br />
<b>Date of Birth:</b> [1998-03-20 8:15:31 pm] <br />
<b>Hobby:</b> [anything]<br /> <b>StudentID:</b>[1.1.1.1] <br /><br />
```

Comment: what i did is to str_replace on all html tags to remove it then i run  preg_match('/\[(.*)?\]\s+/') to parse within inside [] but cannot get accurate data. any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) extension to parse the HTML.

Having said that, your snippet does not look very semantic at all, so perhaps regex might be a better option.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960841/how-to-use-dom-php-parser) for a comprehensive example on how to parse it with DOMDocument.

Comment: wow looks like DOMDocument is quite complicated. Do you have example for regex?