# Removing a select class

Tags: php, class

My problem is the following: i am parsing or scraping or something of the sort a dictionary to use its output as my input (I show the definition, in other words). In this output, several classes are included. There is one class, the class f, which includes the term defined, and a dot following it. This dot disturbes me and I wish to erase it.

[image]

```
<p class="p">

<a href="search?id=D536ScxxE2x5wsXG0ez" target="_self"><img align="right" alt="Ver artículo enmendado" border="0" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAH0AAAAZBAMAAADuyzxaAAAAElBMVEWEAgT8/vz8QkT8AgS8AgT8enxcJRi+AAAA0klEQVQ4y82SwQ3DMAhFOWQBxAJVqwyAWCCHjJDuv0r5OImR2hxqLkEWXxAeBis0vyu20LOCb85XBlidLwywBT8+wBr8y0btNrweGWmifIWwdN/5vVzOPpe8SveJl3z737x6zMJuoq7CzqOlQlhZkRGoQqz5xBty3sULw1kgFoAHbpFEs34S70UeN9QSz2ez6NOwb17sgu8Bypsq/+CB7nyevwf+zfLwmde2ItZgjbGx6fl+sbzE+2GN49zp/y3xNGwT+Mc4T+ALOE0LVa4nWqhoH2NuCULPEni8AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"></a>

<span class="f">

<b>gas</b>

</span>

<span class="f">

<b>.</b>

</span>

</p>
```

Mind you guys that i am using php thoroughly, so in case you need it, here it goes:

```
<?php
    $word = $_REQUEST['word'];


    $url = "http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val={$word}";

    $css = <<<EOT

    <style type="text/css">

    .f /* I GUESS THE PROBLEM IS OVER HERE. I CANT VISIBILITY HIDE F BECAUSE THAT WOULD HIDE "GAS", APART FROM "." */
       {
         margin-left:50px;
         font-size: 200%;
         color: #ffe200;
         font-family: 'brannboll_fetregular';

       }

    </style>
EOT;

$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = str_replace('</head>', $css.'</head>', $data);
echo '<div id="result1"
  style="
  top: 77%;
  left: 55%;
  overflow:scroll; 
  width:400px; 
  height:300px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-opacity: 0.5;
  background: #047C8F;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 13px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow:
               0px 3px 13px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
               inset 0px 0px 13px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -webkit-box-shadow:
               0px 3px 13px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
               inset 0px 0px 13px rgba(0,0,0,1);
 ">
 '.$data.' 
 </div>';
    ?>
```

Comment: Indent the code. Give only the particular one! TL;DR.

Comment: "This dot disturbes me" made me laugh, the pub lunch may not have been such a good idea.

Comment: How is the dot set? With CSS "content:" from the class or is it text within the result?

Comment: Why not put the CSS in a separate file?

Comment: @phpisuber01 text within result i guess

Comment: I would assume that the dot is part of the pull from the url. Echo out the gas part with no css and see if dot is still there

Comment: @user1909426 i like to see it there, not in a separate tab (NetBeans)

Comment: If it always looks like the above code with the dot between bold tags, just do a string replace on the html you're parsing and replace it with ""

Comment: @ROYFinley that sounds nice. Would you be so kind to tell me how? I am less than an amateur. i am echoing the hole output (data). Want me to echo "gas" apart? How can i do this?

Comment: it is fine echo the entire data, just do not add any css to it. this will establish that the dot is in the data and not created by your css. I don't think it is. I think you will need to do a string repalce to get rid of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways that you could try to do this:

**CSS**

You can add a rule that instructs the browser to only show the first span of class `f`:

```
span.f:not(:first-of-type) {
    display:none;
}
```

This might fail in older browsers, specifically in IE8 and before.

**PHP**

Since it looks like the `.` is a predictable string, you could simply replace it:

```
$data = str_replace('<span class="f"><b>.</b></span>', '', $data);
```

This would also work on your "Word Not Found" page - it would simply eliminate the `.`s at the end of each world:

http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=world

**DOM Parsing**

A more robust way to handle this would be to look into a DOM Parser. You can read a brief introduction to DOM Parsing here:

[how to use dom php parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960841/how-to-use-dom-php-parser)

Basically, you would want to find the second `<span class="f">` within the first `<p>`.