# Want to load part of webpage through file_contents_get

Tags: wordpress, html, plugins, domdocument, file-get-contents

I'm trying to develop my knowledge with examples of file_get_contents and I am testing it on the BBC news page, most read (www.bbc.co.uk/news middle right). At the moment I have it loading the whole page, however I wish to only have the Most Read section. I thought of looking at the div and doing preg_match with DOMdocument, however it doesn't have a specific div.

Any ideas how I could load just the most read section onto my wordpress site (alternatively, I tried using wp_remote_get, however it wouldn't load, so either way would be great for me)

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960841/how-to-use-dom-php-parser.  I would recommend using PHP's DOM parser to extract and work with the elements you want.

Comment: The issue here is though, I am looking to scrape it from another website, rather then my own code. I know the Div I am looking for and looked at the $html = file_get_html('example.com');
foreach ($html->find('div[id=interestingbox]') as $result)
{
    echo $result->innertext;
}

however, this simply ended in an error in wordpress, when I punched in the div and website, but i'll have a play around with it. Cheers